# Java socket, create own universal method // vicious circle

Tags: java, compiler-errors, initialization, switch-statement, case-statement

Can you please help me with the answer, please?
I've read a lot, but can understand, how to organize the code.
I want to create my own method to work with the Network and call it time to time in a program.
But this compilation error makes me mad:

variable might be not have been initialized

I do understand why, but I can`t see solution((
My vision is to open Socket and related streams only one time and close it when needed.

```
public static void socket_r (String action, String ip_addr, String to_write, int port)  throws IOException {    

String s;

switch (action) {

            case "Create":      Socket socket = new Socket (ip_addr, port);
                                OutputStream out_from_socket = socket.getOutputStream();
                                PrintWriter writer_socket = new PrintWriter(out_from_socket, true);

                                InputStream input_socket = socket.getInputStream();
                                BufferedReader reader_socket = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_socket));

                                break;                                  

            case "Write":       writer_socket.println(to_write);            
                                writer_socket.println();                

                                break;

            case "Read":        while ((s = reader_socket.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(s);

                                break;

            case "Close":       writer_socket.println(to_write);    
                                writer_socket.println(); 
                                writer_socket.close();
                                reader_socket.close();                                      
                                break;
                }               

}
```

Comment: If you examine the code path your function will take if called with an `action` argument *that isn't* `create`, you might see why you're getting that error.

Comment: perhaps you should look up the singleton design pattern for what you are trying to accomplish, it might be what you are looking for

Comment: The solution is not to write code like this. Write four separate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with why the code won't compile ...

The variables `reader_socket` and `writer_socket` are local variables.  That means:

1. they must be *definitely assigned* before you can use them, and
2. they disappear ... along with their respective values ... when your `socket_r` method returns to the caller.

In your code, there are lots of places where `reader_socket` and `writer_socket` are used without being definitely assigned.  For example:

```
    writer_socket.println(to_write);
```

A call to `socket_r` can reach that statement without passing through any statement that assigns a value to `writer_socket`.  (Yes.  Look at it.)

But here's the problem.  Your *design* requires that a `socket_r("write", ...)` call uses state that only gets initialized in a `socket_r("create", ...)` call.  And then it gets thrown away.

Basically, you **cannot** implement that design using local variables for the state.

So what is the solution?

In order of "goodness"

1. Make the variables `static` variables in the enclosing class.  (This is a bad solution, but it involves the least change to your existing code.   Why it is bad is ... well ... read some more about OO and why `static` should be rarely used.)
2. Make the method non-static method and make the variables instance variables.
3. Solution 2 AND replace `socket_r` with a separate method for each "action".
4. Solution 3 AND put in some extra logic to enforce a proper "life-cycle" for the socket; i.e. create before reads and writes, no reads or writes after close, etcetera.

Basically, you need to *rethink* your design to do things in an OO way, and it will get a whole lot easier.

Comment: Well yes, you absolutely correct, I have to rethink design and yes, I feel that my code is more procedure/functions like in a past insted of OO. But I have some problem with it, as then you have to design main code around operations with Socket. Well, thanks for advice in general, I will thnik how to do refactoring.